# Why does my Java custom cell renderer not show highlighting when the row/cell is selected?

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a custom cell renderer for a cell to do a word wrap so more content can be read. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TextWrapCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TextWrapCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText((String)value);
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),getPreferredSize().height);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);

        return this;
    }
}
```

**Update**: The cell renderer is used properly but when the user selects a row in the JTable, then it only shows the highlighting for the non-custom rendered cells. The highlighting shows for all other cells for that row though. This leaves just one cell with a white background while the rest of the row has blue (in my case) as the highlighted background color.

Comment: Looks like I might be able to use JTable's setSelectionBackground() or grab the selection background using getSelectionBackground() and set the selected cell background in the custom cell renderer code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to check the `isSelected` argument to see if the cell is selected or not, something like:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
{
        setText((String)value);
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),getPreferredSize().height);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (isSelected)
        {
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else
        {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Well if the row is selected does that mean that the cell is selected?

Comment: @Brian The `getTableCellRendererComponent(..., int row, int column)` will handle each cell of a row. So, if a row is selected, all cells under this row should be in selected row mode. You need `isSelected()` to check whether each cell is selected or not since there are many cells in a table.

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense and a copy-n-paste in 3 seconds proved it works.

Comment: I had to add setOpaque(true) on my JLabel to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should call the default implementation first:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);
    ...
```

The default implementation will process all usual arguments such as `isSelected` and `hasFocus`, set the text and background color, activate the focus border etc. Then you will change the displayed text, change the cell size and `return this`.

Comment: He's extending JTextArea so that wont work... (I think you supposed he extended DefaultTableCellRenderer)

Answer (score -1):

Using  setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN); you are telling just what user select is green. What's is your problem and what you expect your code to do?